# Setting field value to Null when using Bulk API

Tags: bulk-api

I am trying to create a Data Load Tool similar to Data Loader which will upload the data from a CSV file to Salesforce. This tool is built using java and using "Bulk API". While this tool works fine, it is only creating problems when I try to insert null values through CSV.

I checked the "[Bulk API Developer Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/datafiles_csv_valid_record_rows.htm)" and it is mentioned that "*Empty field values are ignored when you update records. To set a field value to null, use a field value of #N/A.*"

I wanted to know that is there any alternate way in which i can set the field values to "null" without having to set them to "#N/A" in CSV? Something similar to Data Loader, where blank fields are treated as "null" when we enable "Insert Null Values".

Answer (score 5):

Since this hasn't been responded to after having been posted for several weeks, it would appear that no one has a timely suggestion for you.

My suggestion would be pre-process your CSV files using a script that scans them for field entries containing blank values and inserts a "#N/A" if it finds one. You could do that separately or as part of some kind of "front end" processing by your Utility Tool. You may have some other way of doing that via Java, but I'd think a simple Bat file or VB Script would do the job for you without requiring much work on your part to create it.

Comment: Re-reading this, it sounds like the goal is to write a tool in Java which interacts with Bulk API. In which case instead of pre-processing the CSV it should be trivial to replace null with #N/A as the records are being parsed?

Comment: I'd think so too, but since no one responded, I applied the KISS approach. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I shall give that a try. For now, it has been ageed to continue using #N/A. But if I am able to do wht is suggested, it would definitely save lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you may run into a snag when trying to set a Lookup field to null...

Say you have lookup field `RelatedRecord__c` and normally you set it by specifying a value for `RelatedRecord__r.RelatedRecordExternalID__c`.  You *won't* be able to specify null here (Salesforce will throw an error) ... instead, you'll need to explicitly set `RelatedRecord__c` to null.

Answer (score 0):

@Shailesh: In this case, when you check "Insert Null Values" as true in the Data Loader, The bulk API is disabled in the data loader.

Answer (score -2):

So I think I found a solution to this issue. Instead of setting the field to nil or null, try setting it to the string '#N/A'

```
Empty field values are ignored when you update records. To set a field value to null, use a field value of #N/A.
```

Comment: I'm curious why this is down-voted? The only issue I see with it is there is no citation; the documentation is still online though - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_valid_record_rows.htm

Answer (score -2):

I'm using .NET but had similar issues trying to update fields to null.
Specifically I was trying to update a date field.

Instead of setting TEXT__C = null;

try something like this (where AccountObj is the sfObject to be updated):

```
AccountObj.fieldsToNull = new String[] { "TEXT__c" };
```

I was struggling with this same issue until using the fieldsToNull